# Modification To JS for post script positioning

Tags: javascript

In a previous question I was assisted with JS script which achieved its goal of only showing selected classes, the only problem I have is that the positioning of the displayed classes is not correct.  There are 6 images per row and hundreds of rows.  For arguments sake lets say I select class north it will correctly show just these class elements but if they started on row 2 they will only be showed from that original position in row 2, what needs to be done to bring each new selection up to position 1 of row 1 on the page?

```
<ul id="list"> 
<li>All</li>
<li>North</li>
<li>East</li>
<li>South</li>
<li>West</li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div><img src="image1" class="north all"></div>
  <div><img src="image2" class="east all"></div>
  <div><img src="image3" class="south all"></div>
  <div><img src="image4" class="west all"></div>
  <div><img src="image5" class="west all"></div>
  <div><img src="image6" class="north all"></div>
  <div><img src="image7" class="south all"></div>
  <div><img src="image8" class="south all"></div>
  <div><img src="image9" class="west all"></div>
  <div><img src="image10" class="west all"></div>
  <div><img src="image11" class="north all"></div>
  <div><img src="image12" class="south all"></div>
  <div><img src="image13" class="south all"></div>
</div>


  var list = document.querySelectorAll('#list li')

  for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var item = list[i];
  item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var cl = e.target.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
   if (cl != 'all') {
  var all = document.querySelectorAll('.all')
  for (let j = 0; j < all.length; j++) {
    let a = all[j];
    a.style.display = 'none';
  }
  }
  var all = document.querySelectorAll('.' + cl)
  for (let j = 0; j < all.length; j++) {
    let a = all[j];
    a.style.display = 'block';
   }
  })
 }
```

Comment: Is there CSS I'm missing here? Not sure what you're talking about with the rows and such - http://jsfiddle.net/smrvkw3o/

Comment: yes sorry this is just example code, the actual html is thousands of lines long with over 200 images  under north and south etc classes, and the images are under CSS Grids                                                       .container-content {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
   justify-content: center;
   grid-row-gap: 10px;
   grid-gap:15px;
   background-color: #f3f3f3;}